# How to design a payments database?

Tags: mysql, database-design

I'm writing a progam to control a school.
It's more like a membership subscription schema.
A student applies for a course, and will have to pay an inscription ad a monthly fee, for the rest of a specific time defined by school calendar.

Depending on each case inscription or monthly fees can be reduced for some specific student.
Once a student subscribe to a course, it will be a recurrent payment,
the student can make partial payments.
Also, the student can quit, and never come back.

I have come with something like tables this:

```
STUDENT
+id
+name

COURSE
+id
+name
+inscription_fee
+monthly_fee

SCHEDULED_PAYMENTS
+id
+student_id
+description
+amount

-LEDGER
+id
+student_id
+course_id
+amount
```

But I ended up with long complicated queries when I want to know what a student has  paid, wich monthly fees are due, etc.

So I ask, Is this the right way to design a database for payments? or is there a better way?

Comment: There is rarely, if ever, a "Right Way."

Comment: There are many right ways, but you can't test for those, so your goal should simply be, at first, don't do it the wrong way.

Comment: Is storing  calculated values, and marks the wrong way?

Answer (score 0):

I think all you need is your student table, and your course table, Then a linking table in between to show which student is taking what course

Student
+id, +name

Course
+id, +name, +fee, +monthly_fee

Student_course
+Student_id
+Course_id

then

```
select *
FROM student
JOIN student_course on student.id = student_course.student_id
JOIN course on course.id = student_course.coruse_id
where student.name = ?
```

Then you have both monthly fee and fee, per class for a student

Answer (score -1):

I'd put the ledger and the scheduled payments as 1 table.  When a payment is due add it, and if it gets paid mark it as paid.  But as @Marrgall pointed to there really is no right way to do it, and you' find LOTS of long complicated queries out in the field. so you may as well get use to it.

Comment: Is marking as paid a good practice,?instead of calculated the difference between amount due and amount paid?

Comment: Well when I say marked paid, I was more talking you'd update it there instead of in a separate ledger.  If you kept the ledger I'd link it to the scheduled payments to know what the payment was going too, no need to link it to the student and course, though the course should get linked in the scheduled payments.